# SBS Folder Redirection still applying

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, folder-redirection, small-business

We are migrating from an SBS 2003 to a 2008R2 DC. Currently all user folders are redirected via the default SBS Policy "`Small Business Server Folder Redirection`" **however, this policy currently has no links to any OU.**

How is this policy still applying? If I run a GPO Results it shows it as the "winning" policy for folder redirection, but the GPO itself has no links.

I have confirmed also the setting in the policy is set to `Redirect back to local user profile when user falls out of scope` so this cannot be the problem.

Comment: just apply a new policy that sets the folders to 'store locally' and push that out.  The clients will pull the data back over to their local userprofile

Answer (score 0):

The policy was not removed correctly. As per TechNet documentation:

> Policy Removal . The following table summarizes the behavior of
>   redirected folders and their contents when the GPO no longer applies,
>   based on your selections for policy removal. The following policy
>   removal options are available in the Settings tab, under Policy
>   Removal. ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc732275.aspx))

***Leave the folder in the new location when policy is removed***

Either Enabled or Disabled

• **The folder remains at its redirected location.**

• **The contents remain at the redirected location.**

• **The user continues to have access to the contents at the redirected folder.**

Comment: As per my question, the policy states to redirect the user back to the local profile folder on removal.

Comment: @PnP Its stated, but it was applied to all users before the link got removed ?